# How to display post name right after domain through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have listed post form page *articles* which currently looks like this: 
**http://demo.web/articles/hello-world** 
and I just want to display url which will look something like this: **http://demo.web/hello-world** 
but the problem is the page *articles* will fetch the data with the id passed in the URL.
And, I have also listed other article on the same page with the title other posts. I am already inside **http://demo.web/articles/hello-world** and if I hover over other links of the same page then it gives url which looks like this: 
**http://demo.web/articles/2/hello-world/articles/3/life-is-beautiful**

What I mean to say is the URL is being appended in the existing URL.

At the end what I want my url to look like this: http://demo.web/hello-world or http://demo.web/life-is-beautiful

My .htaccess file have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)/([a-z-]+) articles.php?id=$1&act=$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its like you are rewriting as a relative path.
Try adding / in front "articles.php?id=$1&act=$2"

Comment: Yes, it worked but I want my url to look like this: **http://demo.web/hello-world** or **http://demo.web/life-is-beautiful**  Thanks.